# Элементы административной части bitrix

Tags: html, linux, windows, битрикс, администрирование

Установил виртуальную машину https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/vmbitrix.php . Смотрел все видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kcMGjlhl9VI (а именно меня интересует 1:12:30 - 1:20:00 ). Возник следующий вопрос:

1. Каким элементам административной части bitrix (и вообще какие есть взаимосвязанные элементы, включая блоки html) (в виде последовательности пунктов 
   меню) соответствует пункт меню Форум в нижнем меню footer-а, а также какие есть взаимосвязанные элементы (включая блоки html) с разделом Форум?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]